# For theory of Standard Model Higgs (before knowing its mass), why is branching of Higgs to top-antitop starting to raise before 174*2=348?

Tags: standard-model, higgs

The mass of the top quark is typically around 174 GeV (this is not the object of the question), and evolves over the time with the refined measurements of experiments.

The following figure from LhC Higgs WG, shows the branching ratio of Higgs to various final states, in particular the top-antitop final state.
The mass of the system top-antitop is around $174\times 2=348\ GeV$.

For theory of Standard Model Higgs (before we knew its mass of around 125 GeV), why is branching of Higgs to top-antitop starting to increase well below 348 GeV ?

[image]

Comment: It does not. Might you have misread the mass-axis?

Comment: @rfl : you have an important comment but I don't understand : I see by eye that the red lines start a bit before 348 GeV ? Also, why is BR(H->ttbar) increases and then decreases ?

Comment: I would not give anything on that line starting a bit before 348GeV, or if it did, this might be energy resolution effects, or perhaps whatever top mass they assumed in making the plot... Producing rebar is a bit like a resonance at the center of mass energy

Comment: @rfl : ok thank you